# Firefox losts connection with eventSource

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I'm using Server Sent Events to run a social feed and update it in real time.

Javascript Code :

```
var source = new EventSource('php/stream.php?type=1&encoding=data');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
$.each(data, function(id, object) { 
$('#'+ id).append('<div class="main">'+ object["content"]+'</div><!-- .main -->');
});
};
```

What my PHP send :

```
id: 5
data: json object
retry: 3000
```

Problem :
The script works pretty well but after 10sec +-. It seems like Firefox has lost the connection and doesn't insert the new data. No problem in Safari & Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem and I found that eventsource in firefox doesn't work correctly if you create a local variable. For me I removed the `var` before declaring source, and it worked.
So having it inside `$(document).ready(...)` is fine as long as you don't declare it with a `var`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem because the eventsource code was inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   ...
});
```

take it out.